# How to add values from dictionaries in another dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, addition

I'm so lost in this small program I want to build... 
I have a scoreboard dictionary where I want to add scores from another dictionary. My code is looking something like this:

Edit: I have to add scores, not replace.

```
def addScore(scorebord, scores):
    # add values for common keys between scorebord and scores dictionaries
    # include any keys / values which are not common to both dictionaries

def main():
    scorebord = {}

    score = {'a':1,
             'b':2,
             'c':3}

    addScore(scorebord, score)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Does anyone know how to write this function?

Comment: `scorebord.update(scores)`

Comment: `where I want to add scores from another dictionary`.. what do you mean by `add scores`? Do you mean overwrite scores, add scores where keys are the same, or something else? Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53874786/edit) to give an example input with desired output?

Comment: @coldspeed This will replace, not add the scores, which may or may not be what OP is looking for

Comment: @DeepSpace sure, then again it isn't clear what they meant. They said add but perhaps they referred to adding keys rather than summing/incrementing totals.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear. I indeed meant adding scores to the first dictionary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that when you add the dictionaries, you may have duplicate keys in which you can just add the values together.

```
def addScore(scorebord, scores):
    for key, value in scores.items():
        if key in scorebord:
            scorebord[key] += value
        else:
            scorebord[key] = value

def main():
    scorebord = {}
    score = {'a':1,
             'b':2,
             'c':3}

    addScore(scorebord, score)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It always looks so easy when you see the answer

Comment: Yeah no problem! If you are using Python 2: (for key, value in d.iteritems():)

Answer (score 0):

```
def addScore(scorebord, scores):
    scorebord.update(scores)
```

See more about dictionary update [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/update)

Comment: This will replace, not add the scores, which may or may not be what OP is looking for

Answer (score 0):

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is designed specifically to count positive integers:

```
from collections import Counter

def addScore(scorebord, scores):
    scorebord += scores
    print(scorebord)

def main():
    scorebord = Counter()
    score = Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3})

    addScore(scorebord, score)

main()

# Counter({'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': 1})
```